# Is __attribute__ portable across compilers?

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, clang

I want to make sure my program works on either. Currently, I compile as such:

```
CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wpedantic
```

and want to make sure it works on either Linux/macOS.

I use `__attribute__((unused))` and `__attribute__((noreturn))`. I'm having trouble finding if these are always supported within both `gcc` and `clang`

For example, `clang` [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#noreturn-noreturn) specifies the `[[noreturn]]` syntax only, but [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#maybe-unused-unused) states that `__attribute__((unused))` is also acceptable.

Comment: Never assume or accept what the docs say - ALWAYS TEST!

Comment: I did @Bib. And it compiles, but just because it compiles, doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: Unless part of the specification, nothing beginning with an underscore should be considered portable. It's often used for implementation- and compiler-specific things. Clang modeled lots of their non-portable things after GCC, that's why both have `__attribute__`. Always check the compiler documentation whenever you see anything beginning with an underscore.

Comment: If all you are doing is compiling, then you are not testing. Testing means running and throwing test data at it.

Comment: So both do have `__attribute__` in all cases? @Someprogrammerdude. I specifically meant portable across `gcc` and `clang`.

Comment: Yes, both GCC and Clang have `__attribute__`. But there might be differences in both which attributes are supported and their semantics. Before using an attribute please study the documentation of both compilers carefully. And note that MSVC does *not* (as far as I know) have `__attribute__`, it have its own syntax and special keywords (some which have been copied by at least GCC IIRC).

Comment: Also, when you start using a C23-capable compiler, I urge you to replace as many custom attributes as possible with the (standard attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes).

Comment: I'd just like to add that even if it works on those two compilers, I don't believe the syntax `__attribute__` is specified in the C99 standard, so you'd really just have to test each and every compiler.

Additionally, many compilers do not *fully* comply with the standard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unused` and `noreturn` function attributes are listed in the section [Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) in the GCC manual.  This means that they are supported **by GCC** on every platform, unless otherwise specified.  (Or at least, the maintainers intend it to be supported; bugs are always possible.)  Attributes that are specific to particular target platforms are listed instead in separate sections, e.g. [AArch64 Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/AArch64-Function-Attributes.html), [MIPS Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/MIPS-Function-Attributes.html).

Moreover, for `unused` and `noreturn` in particular, they are purely compile-time features, affecting only the warnings and/or optimizations done by the compiler.  There is nothing about them that would seem platform-dependent, and they are presumably implemented in the generic portion of the compiler that is independent of platform.  So it makes sense that they would work on all platforms.

clang's documentation is less complete, but generally, they aim to provide all of GCC's extensions, except where noted otherwise.  And `unused/noreturn` are very mature features, supported at least as far back as GCC 2.6.3 circa 1994, several years before the LLVM project was even begun.  So I think it's safe to assume that clang supports them.  And it presumably supports them across all platforms, because there is no reason for it not to.  If you found an instance where it wasn't, I'd consider it a clang bug that should be reported.

Of course, you would want to actually test on each platform that your program is advertised as supporting.

It probably goes without saying, but I don't know of any compilers **other** than GCC and clang that support the `__attribute__` syntax at all.  It is not part of ISO standard C.

---

However, ISO C from C23 onward specifies the `[[..]]` syntax for attributes, and includes standard attributes `[[noreturn]]` and `[[maybe_unused]]`.  As GCC and clang both aim for ISO C compliance, they should support this standard syntax as well (you might have to use `--std=c2x` or `--std=c23`), and so will every other C23 compilant compiler.  So moving forward, you will probably want to switch your code to use the ISO syntax.

Comment: I actually looked into it and switched over to the new syntax. Am I correct to say that `__attribute__((noreturn)) == [[noreturn]]` and `__attribute__((unused)) == [[maybe_unused]]`? The “maybe” is throwing me off

Comment: @user129393192: GCC's documentation for `__attribute__((unused))` says: "means that the function is meant to be **possibly** unused".  So IMHO just calling the attribute `unused` was always misleading, and ISO clarified it by adding the `maybe`.  I would presume that GCC handles them identically, but you'd have to check the GCC source code to be certain.